# Cisco AnyConnect disconnects when prompted by UAC

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn, anyconnect

I have a secure network configured with Cisco AnyConnect SSL VPN and Cisco ISE for authentication. (VPN head is a Cisco ASA, AnyConnect v4.5, ISE v2.3)

The client VPN works perfectly except when a user needs to elevate privileges (through UAC). When this occurs, the VPN immediately drops and sometimes fails to reconnect.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this? (Happy to provide additional details where necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the ISE is tracking logon events but acannot understand multiple "logons" from the same host.

The solution appears to be to create an Endpoint Probe on the ISE to monitor the hosts in the target subnet.